# d3 issue with getting data out of a table created from a variable (works in D3.js v3.5.5 but not in v4.2.2)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After executing the following D3.js code (version 4.2.2) in Google Chrome version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit):

```
var svg =   d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 250)
            .attr("height", 250);

function render(data)
{
    //Bind Data
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);

    //Enter
    circles.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10);

    //Update
    circles
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; });

    //Exit
    circles.exit().remove();
}

var myArrayOfObjects = 
[
    { x: 100, y: 100},
    { x: 130, y: 120},
    { x: 60, y: 80},
    { x: 70, y: 110},
    { x: 90, y: 30},
    { x: 20, y: 10}
];

render(myArrayOfObjects);
```

I am getting the following HTML code in the console (elements section):

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>D3 Data binding</title>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>...</script>
  <svg width="250" height="250">
    <circle r="10"></circle>
    <circle r="10"></circle>
    <circle r="10"></circle>
    <circle r="10"></circle>
    <circle r="10"></circle>
    <circle r="10"></circle>
  </svg>
</html>
```

Which leads to this:

[image: The result]

But I want to achieve this:

[image: I have to achieve this]

Anyone knows what can be wrong with my code? My console shows me no errors at all.

Edit: I just tried to run it in 3.5.5 and it worked. It just doesn't work on 4.2.2

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/a08n4986/. Did you tried to clear your browser cache ?

Comment: I did, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think it has to do with the version of d3.js

Comment: @TimB your fiddle is working because you are using D3 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using D3 v 4.x. In this case, you have to `merge` the selections:

```
circles.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10).merge(circles)
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; });
```

This is the [API regarding merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge). You can see it working in the code below:

```js
var svg =   d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", 250)
            .attr("height", 250);

function render(data)
{
    //Bind Data
    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
    
     //Exit
    circles.exit().remove();

    //Enter and Update
    circles.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10).merge(circles)
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; });


}

var myArrayOfObjects = 
[
    { x: 100, y: 100},
    { x: 130, y: 120},
    { x: 60, y: 80},
    { x: 70, y: 110},
    { x: 90, y: 30},
    { x: 20, y: 10}
];

render(myArrayOfObjects);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```